# Toggle Div on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to modify `this` code for click event. But I am not able to do so. My requirement is to slide the panel on click (not hover) and again rollback on click (and not mouse out).

**HTML**

```
<div id="sidePanel">
    <div id="panelContent">
        <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FWebsTutorial&amp;width=200&amp;height=258&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=true&amp;border_color&amp;stream=false&amp;header=false&amp;appId=253401284678598" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:200px; height:258px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>      
    </div>
    <div id="panelHandle"><p>Facebook</p></div>        
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* ===== Primary Styles ========================================================
Author: NTechi | WebsTutorial
========================================================================== */
body{
  font-family:Arial;
}

#sidePanel{
  width:245px;
  position:fixed;
  left:-202px;
  top:15%;    
}
#panelHandle{
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#333,#222);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #333333, #222222);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(center top , #333333, #222222);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(center top , #333333, #222222);
  background-image:linear-gradient(center top , #333333, #222222);

  height:150px;
  width:40px;
  border-radius:0 5px 5px 0;
  float:left;
  cursor:pointer;
}
#panelContent{
  float:left;
  border:1px solid #333333;
  width:200px;
  height:300px;
  background-color:#EEEEEE;
}

#panelHandle p {
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  left: -4px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 26px;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#panelHandle').hover(function() {
        $('#sidePanel').stop(true, false).animate({
            'left': '0px'
        }, 900);
    }, function() {
        jQuery.noConflict();
    });

    jQuery('#sidePanel').hover(function() {
        // Do nothing
    }, function() {

        jQuery.noConflict();
        jQuery('#sidePanel').animate({
            left: '-201px'
        }, 800);

    });
  });
});
```

Any help would be really helpful. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, but I did not get you. The link has the code which I want to modify

Comment: This is not related to your question but `jQuery(function($) {});` and `$(document).ready(function() {});` are the same. So, why are you calling one event inside another identical event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Toggle API Instead http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

```
$('#panelHandle').toggle(function() {
    $('#sidePanel').stop(true, false).animate({
        'left': '0px'
    }, 900);
}, function() {
      jQuery('#sidePanel').animate({
        left: '-201px'
    }, 800);
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GPdFk/4812/

Comment: Thanks a ton. It is working fine now but I have another issue now. My requirement is to place the panel on right hand side and slide it towards left. It was working on hover, but now it is not working and both panel and the handler is invisible now. Sorry if it is very basic question, but I am new to jQuery.

Comment: @user3405976 Can you create or update the fiddle. Not able to understand properly

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to do this. Change the `hover` event to `toggle` event.
Using your jsfiddle it would be something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#panelHandle').toggle(function() {
        $('#sidePanel').stop(true, false).animate({
            'left': '0px'
        }, 900);
    }, function() {
        jQuery.noConflict();
        jQuery('#sidePanel').animate({
            left: '-201px'
        }, 800);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It can easily be done using `.toggle()`

Here is the updated code:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#panelHandle').toggle(function() {
        $('#sidePanel').animate({
            'left': '0px'
        }, 900);
    }, function() {
        $('#sidePanel').animate({
            'left': '-202px'
        }, 900);
    });
});
```